# How to disable warning about listening at high volume for a long time

Tags: volume

I use an ambient sound app through headphones while I sleep. This usually works quite well, except for the occasional night where i get woken up because Android has decided to drop the volume and display a message to the effect of "Listening at high volume for a long time can damage your hearing." I haven't managed to transcribe the exact wording yet because I'm usually grumpy and attempting to get back to sleep when it happens. I'm fairly certain that it can be displayed more than once per reboot cycle, as it was displayed last night despite my having used the phone this way numerous nights over the past couple weeks. (`uptime` currently shows 13 days.)

FWIW, I'm probably risking permanent hearing damage by doing this, but that seems a better bet than the certain negative effects (acuity, mood, cancer) of chronic sleep deprivation.

Is there a way to disable this "feature", with or without root?

Answer (score 4):

According to the article [How to Automatically Disable the High Volume Warning without Root](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-automatically-disable-the-high-volume-warning-without-root/), the warning is implemented on devices due to European legislation which stipulates that:

> all electronic devices capable of media playback sold after February 2013 must have a default output volume level of a maximum 85 dB. Users can choose to override the warning to increase the volume to a maximum of 100 dB, but in doing so the warning must re-appear after 20 hours of music playback.

(The warning should only appear if your device is using an European ROM)

It is possible to disable the warning by following the methods below:

1. **On rooted devices**

If you have the Xposed framework installed, there are several modules (VolumeSteps+ (image on the left), NoSafeVolumeWarning, GravityBox (image on the right), etc) that offer the option to disable the warning.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

2. **On non-rooted devices**

The article above describes methods for disabling the warning using Tasker & AutoTools
either at boot or periodically. It also has a link to download the Tasker's scripts.

In other forums, the app [Hearing Saver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jakebasile.android.hearingsaver&hl=en_ZA) is purported to work on non-rooted devices.

You can also go to Settings --> Apps --> Your_App --> Notifications --> enable `Block Notifications`

Note: I don't use Tasker that is why I have not included the process decribed in the article. However, those who are more knowledgeable with it can include the steps.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  It sounded like there are issues with running Xposed on Samsung devices so I went the Tasker/AutoTools route.  Just finished setting it up and there were a few awkwardly phrased questions and some caveats but hopefully it will work.  I'll leave another reply here in a few days when results are in.

Comment: Hmm, this didn't work (Tasker).  Still haven't found a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 4):

On Samsung Galaxy S9, go to Settings, Sounds and vibration, Volume, and then click on the menu button on the top right-hand corner. The only option is the Media volume limiter. Default is turned off and the Custom volume limit is about 2/3 of the way but grayed out. Turn the setting to On and you can now slide the volume all the way up to the max.

Comment: I don't have an S9 but this doesn't sound like it addresses the issue

Comment: This works on a galaxy a14 too.

Answer (score 0):

My fix for the volume has been to superglue the volume up button so it is always turning volume up. Then root the phone and remove the code in the kernel that activates the warning.

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail about how you "remove the code"? Are you recompiling the kernel or something?