# Can I switch off the automatic volume-down for the 3.5 jack?

Tags: audio, headphone-jack, audio-controls

I use the headphone socket to plug my device into the car speakers and listen to podcasts while I'm driving.

The only way this works is if the device's volume level is on full loudness. You can't hear the show through the car's speakers any other way.

Occasionally, something will trigger something and the device will automatically go significantly quieter and you can only barely hear the show.

The only way to get the sound audible again is to dismiss the on-screen dialog and turn the volume back up. I can't do that while I'm driving so until I can stop safely I have to put up with the show continuing to play in a barely understandable whisper and when I can pull over I have to rewind the show to where I was listening. If the show ended in that time I need to download it again.

Is there please a way to turn off whatever is doing that?

Comment: Most smartphones have a feature to protect you from listening music too loud via headphones as it can damage your haring ability. Unfortunately the smartphone can not know that you don't use headphones at all. What socket do you use on the car side (line-in or something else)? Are there other possibilities to connect your phone to the car?

Comment: @Robert The device only has 3.5 and USB connectors and Bluetooth. The car only has a 3.5 socket.

Comment: I am not sure if this ear protection measure can be disabled. The only alternative I see is using an Bluetooth to Audio receiver that is plugged in into your car. I don't know but it is possible that the maximum output volume of those devices vary, so may be there exists so ne such receiver that better fits TK your car regarding the required volume.

Comment: @Robert Do you know the name of this feature please? (So I can write about it.)

I daresay if I escalated my complaint, the response would be "No, some numpty with a lawyer will switch it off, forget, damage their hearing and sue us."

Comment: What I know is this feature: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203278/2241 And there seems to be a new feature in Android 14.